# Need advice. The following changes causes my stored procedure to EXECUTE for 5mins

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms, partitioning

I have the following view:

```
ALTER VIEW [dbo].[vAccount]
AS
with cte_accounts_data AS 
(
SELECT
         null as CompanyVendorAccountId
        ,CAST(0 as bit) as IsVendorAccount
        ,null as VendorAccountReference
        ,null as VendorCompanyId
        ,a.[AccountId]
        ,a.[CompanyId]
        ,a.[CompanyAccountTypeId]
        ,ag.[CompanyAccountGroupId]
        ,ag.[Name] as CompanyAccountGroupName
        ,a.[RegionId]
        ,a.[Name]
        ,CONCAT(c.ShortName + ': ', a.[Name], ' [' + a.[Code] +']') AS DisplayName
        ,a.[Code]
        ,a.[Address]
        ,a.[Email]
        ,a.[IncludeEscalationEmail]
        ,a.[GPSLat]
        ,a.[GPSLong]
        ,a.[Telephone]
        ,a.[VATNumber]
        ,a.[AutoReceive]
        ,a.[AutoIssue]
        ,a.[IsBillableToAccount]
        ,a.[BillingStart]
        ,a.[IsEquipmentDepot]
        ,a.[IsShiftAttendanceEnabled]
        ,a.[ShiftMinHoursForLunchDeduction]
        ,a.[NightShiftStart]
        ,a.[NightShiftEnd]
        ,a.[ShiftStartDayOfMonth]
        ,a.[OperatingHoursStart]
        ,a.[OperatingHoursEnd]
        ,a.[LoadBays]
        ,a.[LoadInterval]
        ,a.[ArrivalInterval]
        ,a.[OverrideStockTakeCloseBalanceTime]
        --,a.[RFEquipment]
        ,a.[temp_IgnoreVendorIssueViaSAP]
        ,a.[Archived]
        ,a.[CreatedDate]
        ,a.[CreatedBy_PersonId]
        ,a.[UpdatedDate]
        ,a.[UpdatedBy_PersonId]
        ,cat.Name as CompanyAccountTypeName
        ,at.Name as AccountTypeName
        ,at.AccountTypeId
        ,at.EnumAccountType
        ,r.Name as Region
        ,c.Name as Company
        ,CONCAT(c.Code, ': ', a.Name, ' ',a.Code, ' ', c.Name, ' ', r.Name, ' ', at.Name, ' ', r.Code, ' ') as ViewSearchColumn
    FROM
        [Account] a
    JOIN Company c on (a.CompanyId = c.CompanyId)
    JOIN CompanyAccountType cat on (a.CompanyAccountTypeId = cat.CompanyAccountTypeId)
    JOIN AccountType at on (cat.AccountTypeId = at.AccountTypeId)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN vCompanyAccountGroup ag on (a.CompanyAccountGroupId = ag.CompanyAccountGroupId)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Region r on (a.RegionId = r.RegionId)

    UNION 

    SELECT
         cv.[CompanyVendorAccountId]
        ,CAST(1 as bit) as IsVendorAccount
        ,cv.[VendorAccountReference]
        ,a.[CompanyId] as VendorCompanyId
        ,a.[AccountId]
        ,cv.[CompanyId]
        ,cv.[CompanyAccountTypeId]
        ,ag.[CompanyAccountGroupId]
        ,ag.[Name] as CompanyAccountGroupName
        ,a.[RegionId]
        ,a.[Name]
        ,CONCAT(c.ShortName + ': ', a.[Name], ' [' + cv.[VendorAccountReference] +']') AS DisplayName
        ,cv.[VendorAccountReference] as [Code]
        ,a.[Address]
        ,a.[Email]
        ,a.[IncludeEscalationEmail]
        ,a.[GPSLat]
        ,a.[GPSLong]
        ,a.[Telephone]
        ,a.[VATNumber]
        ,a.[AutoReceive]
        ,a.[AutoIssue]
        ,a.[IsBillableToAccount]
        ,a.[BillingStart]
        ,a.[IsEquipmentDepot]
        ,a.[IsShiftAttendanceEnabled]
        ,a.[ShiftMinHoursForLunchDeduction]
        ,a.[NightShiftStart]
        ,a.[NightShiftEnd]
        ,a.[ShiftStartDayOfMonth]
        ,a.[OperatingHoursStart]
        ,a.[OperatingHoursEnd]
        ,a.[LoadBays]
        ,a.[LoadInterval]
        ,a.[ArrivalInterval]
        ,a.[OverrideStockTakeCloseBalanceTime]
        --,a.[RFEquipment]
        ,a.[temp_IgnoreVendorIssueViaSAP]
        ,cv.[Archived]
        ,cv.[CreatedDate]
        ,cv.[CreatedBy_PersonId]
        ,cv.[UpdatedDate]
        ,cv.[UpdatedBy_PersonId]
        ,cat.Name as CompanyAccountTypeName
        ,at.Name as AccountTypeName
        ,at.AccountTypeId
        ,at.EnumAccountType
        ,r.Name as Region
        ,c.Name as Company
        ,CONCAT(c.Code, ': ', a.Name, ' ',a.Code, ' ', c.Name, ' ', r.Name, ' ', at.Name, ' ', r.Code, ' ') as ViewSearchColumn
    FROM
        [CompanyVendorAccount] cv
    JOIN Company c on (cv.CompanyId = c.CompanyId)
    JOIN CompanyAccountType cat on (cv.CompanyAccountTypeId = cat.CompanyAccountTypeId)
    JOIN AccountType at on (cat.AccountTypeId = at.AccountTypeId)
    JOIN Account a on (cv.VendorAccountId = a.AccountId)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Region r on (a.RegionId = r.RegionId)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN vCompanyAccountGroup ag on (cv.CompanyAccountGroupId = ag.CompanyAccountGroupId)
    WHERE
        cv.CompanyId != a.CompanyId
)
,cte_ranking_order as 
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() over (ORDER BY AccountId, CompanyId) as rankNumber,* FROM cte_accounts_data
)
SELECT  [CompanyVendorAccountId] 
       ,IsVendorAccount
       ,[VendorAccountReference]
       ,[VendorCompanyId]
       ,[AccountId]
       ,[CompanyId]
       ,[CompanyAccountTypeId]
       ,[CompanyAccountGroupId]
       ,[CompanyAccountGroupName]
       ,[RegionId]
       ,[Name]
       ,[DisplayName]
       ,[Code]
       ,[Address]
       ,[Email]
       ,[IncludeEscalationEmail]
       ,[GPSLat]
       ,[GPSLong]
       ,[Telephone]
       ,[VATNumber]
       ,[AutoReceive]
       ,[AutoIssue]
       ,[IsBillableToAccount]
       ,[BillingStart]
       ,[IsEquipmentDepot]
       ,[IsShiftAttendanceEnabled]
       ,[ShiftMinHoursForLunchDeduction]
       ,[NightShiftStart]
       ,[NightShiftEnd]
       ,[ShiftStartDayOfMonth]
       ,[OperatingHoursStart]
       ,[OperatingHoursEnd]
       ,[LoadBays]
       ,[LoadInterval]
       ,[ArrivalInterval]
       ,[OverrideStockTakeCloseBalanceTime]
       ,[temp_IgnoreVendorIssueViaSAP]
       ,[Archived]
       ,[CreatedDate]
       ,[CreatedBy_PersonId]
       ,[UpdatedDate]
       ,[UpdatedBy_PersonId]
       ,[CompanyAccountTypeName]
       ,[AccountTypeName]
       ,[AccountTypeId]
       ,[EnumAccountType]
       ,[Region]
       ,[Company]
       ,[ViewSearchColumn]
    FROM cte_ranking_order where rankNumber = 1
GO
```

Which I modified to look like the above.

Below is the original View:

```
    ALTER VIEW [dbo].[vAccount]
AS

with cte_accounts_data AS 
(
SELECT
         null as CompanyVendorAccountId
        ,CAST(0 as bit) as IsVendorAccount
        ,null as VendorAccountReference
        ,null as VendorCompanyId
        ,a.[AccountId]
        ,a.[CompanyId]
        ,a.[CompanyAccountTypeId]
        ,ag.[CompanyAccountGroupId]
        ,ag.[Name] as CompanyAccountGroupName
        ,a.[RegionId]
        ,a.[Name]
        ,CONCAT(c.ShortName + ': ', a.[Name], ' [' + a.[Code] +']') AS DisplayName
        ,a.[Code]
        ,a.[Address]
        ,a.[Email]
        ,a.[IncludeEscalationEmail]
        ,a.[GPSLat]
        ,a.[GPSLong]
        ,a.[Telephone]
        ,a.[VATNumber]
        ,a.[AutoReceive]
        ,a.[AutoIssue]
        ,a.[IsBillableToAccount]
        ,a.[BillingStart]
        ,a.[IsEquipmentDepot]
        ,a.[IsShiftAttendanceEnabled]
        ,a.[ShiftMinHoursForLunchDeduction]
        ,a.[NightShiftStart]
        ,a.[NightShiftEnd]
        ,a.[ShiftStartDayOfMonth]
        ,a.[OperatingHoursStart]
        ,a.[OperatingHoursEnd]
        ,a.[LoadBays]
        ,a.[LoadInterval]
        ,a.[ArrivalInterval]
        ,a.[OverrideStockTakeCloseBalanceTime]
        --,a.[RFEquipment]
        ,a.[temp_IgnoreVendorIssueViaSAP]
        ,a.[Archived]
        ,a.[CreatedDate]
        ,a.[CreatedBy_PersonId]
        ,a.[UpdatedDate]
        ,a.[UpdatedBy_PersonId]
        ,cat.Name as CompanyAccountTypeName
        ,at.Name as AccountTypeName
        ,at.AccountTypeId
        ,at.EnumAccountType
        ,r.Name as Region
        ,c.Name as Company
        ,CONCAT(c.Code, ': ', a.Name, ' ',a.Code, ' ', c.Name, ' ', r.Name, ' ', at.Name, ' ', r.Code, ' ') as ViewSearchColumn
    FROM
        [Account] a
    JOIN Company c on (a.CompanyId = c.CompanyId)
    JOIN CompanyAccountType cat on (a.CompanyAccountTypeId = cat.CompanyAccountTypeId)
    JOIN AccountType at on (cat.AccountTypeId = at.AccountTypeId)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN vCompanyAccountGroup ag on (a.CompanyAccountGroupId = ag.CompanyAccountGroupId)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Region r on (a.RegionId = r.RegionId)

    UNION 

    SELECT
         cv.[CompanyVendorAccountId]
        ,CAST(1 as bit) as IsVendorAccount
        ,cv.[VendorAccountReference]
        ,a.[CompanyId] as VendorCompanyId
        ,a.[AccountId]
        ,cv.[CompanyId]
        ,cv.[CompanyAccountTypeId]
        ,ag.[CompanyAccountGroupId]
        ,ag.[Name] as CompanyAccountGroupName
        ,a.[RegionId]
        ,a.[Name]
        ,CONCAT(c.ShortName + ': ', a.[Name], ' [' + cv.[VendorAccountReference] +']') AS DisplayName
        ,cv.[VendorAccountReference] as [Code]
        ,a.[Address]
        ,a.[Email]
        ,a.[IncludeEscalationEmail]
        ,a.[GPSLat]
        ,a.[GPSLong]
        ,a.[Telephone]
        ,a.[VATNumber]
        ,a.[AutoReceive]
        ,a.[AutoIssue]
        ,a.[IsBillableToAccount]
        ,a.[BillingStart]
        ,a.[IsEquipmentDepot]
        ,a.[IsShiftAttendanceEnabled]
        ,a.[ShiftMinHoursForLunchDeduction]
        ,a.[NightShiftStart]
        ,a.[NightShiftEnd]
        ,a.[ShiftStartDayOfMonth]
        ,a.[OperatingHoursStart]
        ,a.[OperatingHoursEnd]
        ,a.[LoadBays]
        ,a.[LoadInterval]
        ,a.[ArrivalInterval]
        ,a.[OverrideStockTakeCloseBalanceTime]
        --,a.[RFEquipment]
        ,a.[temp_IgnoreVendorIssueViaSAP]
        ,cv.[Archived]
        ,cv.[CreatedDate]
        ,cv.[CreatedBy_PersonId]
        ,cv.[UpdatedDate]
        ,cv.[UpdatedBy_PersonId]
        ,cat.Name as CompanyAccountTypeName
        ,at.Name as AccountTypeName
        ,at.AccountTypeId
        ,at.EnumAccountType
        ,r.Name as Region
        ,c.Name as Company
        ,CONCAT(c.Code, ': ', a.Name, ' ',a.Code, ' ', c.Name, ' ', r.Name, ' ', at.Name, ' ', r.Code, ' ') as ViewSearchColumn
    FROM
        [CompanyVendorAccount] cv
    JOIN Company c on (cv.CompanyId = c.CompanyId)
    JOIN CompanyAccountType cat on (cv.CompanyAccountTypeId = cat.CompanyAccountTypeId)
    JOIN AccountType at on (cat.AccountTypeId = at.AccountTypeId)
    JOIN Account a on (cv.VendorAccountId = a.AccountId)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Region r on (a.RegionId = r.RegionId)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN vCompanyAccountGroup ag on (cv.CompanyAccountGroupId = ag.CompanyAccountGroupId)
    WHERE
        cv.CompanyId != a.CompanyId
```

The only think I added, was this cte:

```
 ,cte_ranking_order as 
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION BY AccountId, CompanyID ORDER BY AccountId, CompanyId) as rankNumber,* FROM cte_accounts_data
)
```

The point of this was to only select unique Accounts from the original select lsits, by giving it a `ROW_NUMBER()` and partitioning the data with `over (PARTITION BY AccountId, CompanyID ORDER BY AccountId, CompanyId)`.

When a stored procedure tries to join this View with some other views, passed in a specific `@AccountId`, the stored procedure executes for about 5min.

I really am not sure what could posiible cause this?

Comment: We need more than a bunch of code to help with performance problems. Can you post the execution plan? https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/

Comment: Let me get it quick

Comment: @SeanLange Unfortunatly my execution plan is larger than 2MB

Comment: Well that might be an indication of things not going quite right. Can you post the plan somewhere? My guess is the sorting is killing you here due to a lack of covering indexes.

Comment: Also, please considere adding table definitions with index declarations. This will help diagnose the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I was going to add this as a comment, but I couldn't really give you a good example of what I was trying to say...

Have you eliminated SQL's parameter sniffing as the culprit? I've had it happen many times, running the query in a query window is fast, but the sp takes forever. This can happen when parameter sniffing kicks in. You can avoid this by assigning the passed variables to new variables within the SP and then referencing those instead.

So, for example:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.MyProcedureName(
    @AccountID INT
)
BEGIN

    -- Prevent parameter sniffing.
    DECLARE @MyAccountID INT = @AccountID;

    SELECT
        ...
    FROM dbo.MyView
    WHERE
        MyView.AccountID = @MyAccountID;

   ...

END
```

Just a thought, but this has happened to me before and I beat my head against a wall trying to figure it out.

I know there are other ways (perhaps better) to handle this particular problem, but this solution has always worked for me.

Some additional reading on the subject if interested:
https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/parameter-sniffing/